# How can I make a Boolean that can be accessed from one class to another

Tags: java, plugins, command, boolean

I currently have two classes Main and Command.
They are both inside of the package emerica.simple 
So the classpath is emerica.simple.Main and emerica.simple.Command

In main I define a Boolean called spyblock

`public class Main extends JavaPlugin{
    public static boolean spyblock = true;`

In command I am trying to access it and change it

```
public class Command implements CommandExecutor {
public boolean onCommand(CommandSender sender, Command cmd, String label, String[] args) {
    if (cmd.getName().equalsIgnoreCase("spyblocks")) {
        return true;
        if (Main.spyblock == true) {

            Main.spyblock = false;
        }
        else {
            Main.spyblock = true;
        }
    } 
    else 
    {
        return false;
    }
}
```

Hoe can I change this code so it works? I am trying to toggle main.spyblock this the command "Spyblocks"

Comment: Where is a error? What is output?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your code for altering spyblock is not reachable because of

```
if (cmd.getName().equalsIgnoreCase("spyblocks")) {
        **return true;**
        if (Main.spyblock == true) {

            Main.spyblock = false;
        }
        else {
            Main.spyblock = true;
        }
    }
```

highlighted line. just move this like

```
if (cmd.getName().equalsIgnoreCase("spyblocks")) {

        if (Main.spyblock == true) {

            Main.spyblock = false;
        }
        else {
            Main.spyblock = true;
        }
        **return true;**
    }
```

Hope this helps

Answer (score 0):

You have `unreachable code` :

```
if (cmd.getName().equalsIgnoreCase("spyblocks")) {
    return true;
     //unreachable code
    if (Main.spyblock == true) {

        Main.spyblock = false;
    }
    else {
        Main.spyblock = true;
    }
}
```

That's why value of `Main.spyblock` doesn't change.

You returned your method just above your 2nd `if` i.e. `return true;`, that's why your `if` is not executing, you have to put `return true;` after your 2nd `if-else` condition.

Comment: How do I make it reachable?

Answer (score 0):

If you just want to toggle it do it like this:

```
if (cmd.getName().equalsIgnoreCase("spyblocks")) {
   Main.spyblock = !Main.spyblock;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

I don't fully understsand what you  are trying to do, but currently your code won't compile properly.

Try changing it to the following

```
public class Command implements CommandExecutor {
public boolean onCommand(CommandSender sender, Command cmd, String label, String[] args) {
    if (cmd.getName().equalsIgnoreCase("spyblocks")) {
        if (Main.spyblock == true) {
            Main.spyblock = false;
        }
        else {
            Main.spyblock = true;
        } 
        return true;
    }
    return false;
}
```

You can also change your logic, making it a bit simpler, since you do not have to check for both conditions, since you are always toggling it. Therefore just always set it to the opposite of what it currently is.

```
    Main.spyblock = !Main.spyblock;
```